# Is there a way to have snapd start while I'm logging in

Tags: snap, startup, systemd

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` suggests that snap-related services are the main cause of startup latency on my system:

```
graphical.target @3.300s
└─multi-user.target @3.299s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @3.170s +127ms
    └─snapd.service @2.275s +885ms
      └─basic.target @2.194s
        └─sockets.target @2.193s
          └─snapd.socket @2.180s +12ms
            └─sysinit.target @2.146s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @2.054s +91ms
                └─apparmor.service @1.848s +177ms
```

While I've given up on trying to disable snap none of the snaps that I have installed need to start before I log in. So it seems like I could speed up my boot by making systemd's `multi-user.target` not wait for `snapd.seeded.service` and have `snapd` keep starting while I'm typing my password and my gnome session starts. Is there a way to achieve this (hopefully by modifying the `snapd.service` file in `/lib/systemd/system/`)?

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 btw

Comment: REMINDER: changing system files directly will make trouble in several cases, e.g. upgrade. Use `systemctl edit ...` (see `man systemctl`).

Comment: Reaching `multi-user.target` in only 3.299 seconds seems the contradict the claim of latency or slow-boot. That's mighty fast.